# IIS 7.5 UrlRewrite rule for 301 redirect to lowercase url

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I need a Url-rewrite rule to make a 301-redirect to url in lowercase.
For example http://example.com/CurRENcies/USD should become http://example.com/currencies/usd.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

How can I do this redirects only for GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^.*[A-Z]+.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```